# Hough transform improvement

Tags: qgis, hough-transform

I used the Hough transform once but it didn't get enough of the buildings.
So I tried the Hough transform again by adding other steps. Still not enough, what else can I do?

- The image I used: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eYhufJrJlYNPVGa8_nTPR1Fkm0ISrV9M/view?usp=sharing

[image: first try hough transform;]

Steps I followed to improve the Hough transform (GRASS and QGIS);

1. `i.edge input=goruntu output=1EDGEraster`
2. `r.colors input=1EDGEraster color=grey1.0 output=edgegray`
3. `r.null input=edgegray setnull=0 output=nulls`

[image: Null raster]

4. `r.grow input=nulls 3.01 radians output=Grow`

[image: grow raster]

5. `r.thin input=Grow output=THIN`
6. `r.colors -n map=THIN@deneme color=grey1.0`

[image: THIN raster]

7. `r.houghtransform --overwrite input=THIN@deneme output=THINHOUGH lines_number=100 gap_size=3 max_gap=30 line_width=15`

[image: HOUGHraster]

[image: Houghraster close-up]